# Spring XD : File sink with date parameter

Tags: spring-xd

I have just installed spring xd for doing a POC. My initial goal is to install spring xd on all the application server, collect the logs of the day and dump it to a location in a  NFS mount. I have setup spring xd in the distribution mode. My stream looks something like this

stream create --name teststream --definition "file --dir= | file --dir ="

I want the file sink to dump to a directory based on current date . For example /tmp/xd/output_9242014

How do I achieve this ? Are there are any date functions available today ? Please help